# How to load external js file in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `data.js` file with the following structure:

```
var DATA= {
  "groups": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "group 1",
    "subgroups": [{}, {}, ...]
  }, ...],
  ...
}
```

Is it possible to load this file in my React app and make the DATA var available in any component (I will probably want to initiate Redux state with it), if I can't use `export` in this file and can't turn it into regular JSON file? Basically I can't edit this file. How can it be achieved?

Comment: then look for dynamic imports.

Comment: check this once https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/Declaratively_loading_JS_libraries/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming:**

- The `data.js` file is available during build time
- File has content in pre-defined format
- You are using webpack to bundle your application(Optional)

You can use webpack `raw-loader`(Other bundlers probably have alternatives) to load the content of the file and then parse the content to get the required data.

Example

[image: Edit 1o92xyn41q]

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use export in .js file. `export default` or `module.exports` should work. If you aren't using a language transformer then use the later approach.

```
var DATA = {
  "groups": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "group 1",
    "subgroups": [{}, {}, ...]
  }, ...],
  ...
}

module.exports = DATA;
```

Otherwise convert the file into `json` format and directly use it.

```
{
  "groups": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "group 1",
    "subgroups": [{}, {}, ...]
  }, ...],
  ...
}
```

React app file.js:

```
import data from './data.json';

// do something with data.groups
```

Comment: First of all thank you for the answer! However, I probably didn't explain the issue well enough: I know I can, i.e. able, to use `export` in this file or turn it to JSON. The thing is I have (must) use the file as is, without editing it.

Comment: _Basically I can't edit this file._...I suppose you missed this line.

Comment: so basically that data.js file doesn't belong to you? @Igal

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you just have a file with this exact structure and are looking for a way to access it in your app. Since it uses a var declaration, you can just include it in your web app via a `<script>` tag and DATA variable will be globally available in your code. 
If you use TypeScript or FlowType, you should also provide a declaration file with `declare var DATA: Data;` where `Data` would be your custom interface describing the structure of this data object. 
What I would suggest instead, though, is creating a single module that will consume the variable, provide a declaration in this module only, transform it however I like and export it from there. Just to give you an idea what it would look like:

```
interface Data {
    groups: Group[];
}

interface Group {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    subgroups: {}[];  // you might provide more type information here, but to begin it would do as well
}

declare var DATA: Data;

const APP_DATA: Data = DATA;
export default APP_DATA;
```