# Is there are proper way to develop Samsung TV (Tizen) app with React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app, tizen-tv

I need to develop an application for Samsung TV and I know it can be developed with Tizen Studio but I would like to use React. When I build React application and launch it on TV it works fine, however I need to access Samsung Product APIs that is loaded via

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="$WEBAPIS/webapis/webapis.js"></script>
```

I tried downloading all webapis.js code and load it in React application but I get `'webapis' is not defined` error.

Is there are a proper way to load webapis.js file in React application, so I could access Samsung Product API methods?

Comment: Can this help you? This is a way to load external Javascript file in React https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54288593/how-to-load-external-js-file-in-react

Comment: @Gido Did you find a good solution for this? I have a similar issue where I would like to play videos based on the webapis in the browser

Comment: I have attached webapis to window object - window.webapis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webapis are attached to the window object in your app. You should not try to bring webapis.js to your app package. It's would be available to you once running on TV.

If you are developing in the browser you can write your own wrapper function that handles the lack of that method with a try-catch block.

```
let = getTVFW() => {
    let value;
    try {
        value = window.webapis.productinfo.getFirmware();
        console.log(" Firmware value = " + value);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(" error code = " + error.code);
        value = 'testvaluefordev';
    }
    return value;
}
```

The above can be a service of some sort that your app is using and you reference that function to access what you need.

Also, make sure you have correct privileges that allow you to access these APIs.